# How to change Property name in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two property in my Model class. I am using MVC 4. For example i am having below class and its belonging property -

```
public Class Test 
{  
   public string Custom1 {get; set;}    
   public string Custom2 {get; set;}   
}
```

When i am binding this Test model class, it working properly. What i want, i want to keep property name Custom1 and Custom2 but want to change its name.

Means, Custom1 will be there but i am accessing this property with different name like EmailId and Password instead of Custom1 and Custom2.

Comment: Why should you do that? I suppose you have a weird problem when re-naming properties within your model. If a class should provide the same functionalities but with different names it should be its own class.

Answer (score 9):

If you want a different display name this would help:

```
[DisplayName("EmailId")]
public string Custom1{ get; set; }

[DisplayName("Password")]
public string Custom2{ get; set; }
```

Comment: UPVOTE - I mean OP want this!

Comment: Thanks, Today this is the right way: [Display(Name ="Password")]

Answer (score 3):

Something like this ?

```
public Class Test 
{  
   public string Custom1 {get; set;}
   public string Custom1OtherName
   {
         get { return this.Custom1; }
         set { this.Custom1 = value; }
   } 
   public string Custom2 {get; set;}   
}
```

Unless you mean you want to define it at run time?

Answer (score 2):

This might help:

```
    public class Test 
    {  
       public string Custom1 {get; set;}    
       public string Custom2 {get; set;}

        public string EmailId
        {
            get { return Custom1; }
            set { Custom1 = value; }
        }
    }
```